# Detach SQL Server database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, detach

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = master; Integrated Security = True;";
con.Open();

string str = "USE master;" +
"EXEC sp_detach_db @dbname = N'PhoneBookDB'";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Detached", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
Application.Exit();
```

I get this error:

> Cannot detach the database 'PhoneBookDB' because it is currently in use.
>   Changed database context to 'master'.

What should I do?

Comment: and no one else is using the db?

Comment: Have you tried setting your database to offline and/or single user before detaching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = master; Integrated Security = True;";
con.Open();

string str = "USE master;" +
"ALTER DATABASE PhoneBookDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; EXEC sp_detach_db @dbname = N'PhoneBookDB'";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Detached", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    Application.Exit();
```

You can also try used `sp_who` or `sp_whoisactive` to find the current connections and kill them.